# In need of a detailed working example of gae datastore with django

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I've search and searched but i cannot find a working example.

i am a beginner, just started working with gae for about a week.

ive created some pages using bottle, jinja, with sqlite3. i know how to create pages using django and etc, but ive no clue how to use the datastore.

please, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: if you want my opinion don't use django on gae. its not made for gae and all django implementations are patches to django to make it work on the gae environment.

Comment: @aschmid00 thanks for the info! as much as i dont want to use django, my professor is requiring it. i have all my pages etc all set up but i have yet to figure out how to use the datastore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have access to Cloud SQL? Here are some instructions:

https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/django

Otherwise, it's pretty straightforward. Just wire up Django via WSGI.